# Is there a way that the LABEL CONTROL will automatically move to the left so that the text of the LABEL will not be truncated?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

Here is the sample code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //text values will be coming from database
        label1.Text = "Sample 1";//db value
        label2.Text = "Sample 2";//db value
        label3.Text = "Sample 3";//db value
    }
```

Here is the ouput:

[image]

The text was truncated. How can I fix this? Is there a way that the label will adjust to the left automatically, the text has different lengths

Comment: @AVD its turned on by default

Comment: @GrayFullBuster you need to position the label control manually by noting the length.

Comment: May be you need to use the `anchor` property of the label...

Comment: Try setting the label text `right aligned` and place your label close to your text box..

Comment: @dotNETbeginner where is the align text right? :)

Comment: @GrayFullBuster: click on your label and press `F4` there in properties you will find it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have to use `TableLayoutPanel` and create `Columns` with `SizeType=AutoSize`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Turn on the auto size property and **align the text right**

This way, label will auto grow on left.

Edit:

To keep the things in place, you might also have to use either table layout panel or a flow layout panel.

Comment: Go to the properties of control (select control and press F4) and change the value of TextAlignment property to MiddleRight

Answer (score 1):

Set the following properties in your label

```
    AutoSize = false;
    Anchor = Top, Right
    TextAlign = MiddleLeft
```